# Eclipse Groovy Annotation Autocomplete/Quick Fix

Tags: eclipse, groovy, autocomplete, annotations

When writing Java in eclipse, I can hit Control-1 on some non-imported resource, and use eclipse's class lookup to create the import for me. Huge time-saver. This should work for both classes and annotations.

When writing Groovy in eclipse, the class lookup works, but when I do the quick fix on annotations it doesn't even try to help me. This really sucks because so many frameworks are annotation-based. I have to go back to the dark ages and lookup the correct import statements for jUnit, Spring, Hibernate, etc etc.

Please help!

EDIT:

I should mention that I'm using OSX 10.7.4 and Eclipse Indigo.

Also, I just noticed that Control-Spacebar sort of works. Only problem is that it's not aware of the annotation so I have to manually filter through classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that feature is not implemented.  You could try doing CMD+Shift+O for organize imports.  That should find what you're looking for.

Comment: Good enough solution for now until they add official support for this. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this feature is now implemented in Groovy-Eclipse 2.7.1 (released today).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have the annotation autocomplete turned off? This works for me...

Comment: It's a clean install of the Groovy plugin. And I can't find this option anywhere. How can I turn it back on?

Comment: On the Mac it's Preferences | Java | Editor | Content Assist | Advanced